# No Display Device listed under Color Management

Tags: windows-8.1, display, color-profiles

My monitor, a Dell S2340L, is not being listed under Color Management. Any solutions for this?

[image: 1]

I'm using Windows 8.1 fully updated. I have tried `sfc /scannow` but it has not helped me.

Answer (score -1):

The TeamViewer Black Screen Display Driver was causing the issue. After I have uninstalled the driver, it showed up fine